# artifact not available in maven central vaadin

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin7

if I look at:

> vaadin.com/vaadin-8/releases/7.7.21

I can see that version 7.7.21 is available, while on maven central is not available

> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Now I wonder why?
Besides if I look at:

> https://vaadin.com/support/vaadin-7-extended-maintenance

there is written that version 7.7.23 has "Changed license from Apache 2.0 to CVDLv4.", that means "I cannot use 7.7.22 anymore? without paying?

Comment: The linked site states: **Vaadin 7.7.17 was the last public open-source version of the Vaadin 7 framework.**

Comment: ok, but why I can download from vaadin.com/vaadin-8/releases/7.7.21 ? this release is not available on maven but it can be downloaded? thanks

Answer (score 1):

We released 7.7.18 to 7.7.22 in private maven repository (password available only for those who have subscription) and changed distribution mechanism since version 7.7.23. Regardless of distribution mechanism Vaadin 7.7.18+ is no longer a free product. Legit use requires to obtain license of Vaadin 7 Extended Support, which is option included in Vaadin's Prime subscription.